# How to change iOS ported macOS Catalyst app name?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, mac-catalyst

After porting the app over to macOS using Catalyst, the window now has the correct app name; however, app names for the actual app in the Applications folder, the menu bar, and Dock is the Xcode project Target name.

How to change it to the correct product name without changing the project target name?

Answer (score 0):

In your project’s Build Settings, change `Product Name` to whatever custom string you want it to be.

There may be other settings that use `$(PRODUCT_NAME)` and you don’t want them to change; if so, change them to use `$(TARGET_NAME)` instead.